Bokeh server only shows white page
I am trying to run a Bokeh server that shows an interface in browser with two candlestick charts that compare the data of two stocks. The browser opens with command bokeh serve --show main.py
but all that appears is a blank page.
i was expecting to get a page in my browser that shows 4 inputs, first two for stock tickers, second two for start date and end date.
After input there should be two charts next to each other to visualize the data.
I am getting this error in the terminal:
UserWarning: 
It looks like you might be running the main.py of a directory app directly.
If this is the case, to enable the features of directory style apps, you must
call "bokeh serve" on the directory instead. For example:

    bokeh serve my_app_dir/

If this is not the case, renaming main.py will suppress this warning.

  sys.exit(main())
2024-04-27 13:12:56,435 Starting Bokeh server version 3.4.1 (running on Tornado 6.4)
2024-04-27 13:12:56,436 User authentication hooks NOT provided (default user enabled)
2024-04-27 13:12:56,439 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/main
2024-04-27 13:12:56,439 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 8136
2024-04-27 13:12:57,450 Error running application handler <bokeh.application.handlers.script.ScriptHandler object at 0x7ded45d1e150>: cannot import name 'tow' from 'bokeh.layouts' (/home/cameron/Documents/Code/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/bokeh/layouts.py)
File 'main.py', line 9, in <module>:
from bokeh.layouts import tow, column Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cameron/Documents/Code/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/code_runner.py", line 229, in run
    exec(self._code, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/cameron/Documents/Code/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bokeh.layouts import tow, column
ImportError: cannot import name 'tow' from 'bokeh.layouts' (/home/cameron/Documents/Code/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/bokeh/layouts.py)
 
2024-04-27 13:12:57,792 WebSocket connection opened
2024-04-27 13:12:57,793 ServerConnection created
2024-04-27 13:13:19,808 WebSocket connection closed: code=1001, reason=None

Here is the code:
import math
import datetime as dt

import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import TextInput, Button, DatePicker, MultiChoice

def load_data(ticker1, ticker2, start, end):
    df1 = yf.download(ticker1, start, end)
    df2 = yf.download(ticker2, start, end)
    return df1, df2

def plot_data(data, indicators, sync_axis=None):
    df = data
    gain = df.Close > df.Open
    loss = df.Open > df.Close
    width = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    if sync_axis is not None:
        p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save", width=1000,
                   x_range=sync_axis)
    else:
        p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save", width=1000)

    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi / 4
    p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.25

    p.segment(df.index, df.High, df.index, df.Low, color="black")
    p.vbar(df.index[gain], width, df.Open[gain], df.Close[gain], fill_color="#00ff00", line_color="00ff00")
    p.vbar(df.index[loss], width, df.Open[loss], df.Close[loss], fill_color="#ff0000", line_color="ff0000")


def on_button_click(ticker1, ticker2, start, end, indicators):
    df1, df2 = load_data(ticker1, ticker2, start, end)
    p1 = plot_data(df1, indicators)
    p2 = plot_data(df2, indicators, sync_axis=p1.x_range)
    curdoc().clear()
    curdoc().add_root(layout)
    curdoc().add_root(row(p1, p2))



stock1_text = TextInput(title='Stock 1')
stock2_text = TextInput(title='Stock 2')
date_picker_from = DatePicker(title="Start date", value="2020-01-01", min_date="2000-01-01", 
                              max_date=dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
date_picker_to = DatePicker(title="End date", value="2020-02-01", min_date="2000-01-01", 
                              max_date=dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
indicator_choice = MultiChoice(options=["100 Day SMA", "30 Day SMA", "Linear Regression line"])

load_button = Button(label="Load Data", button_type="success")
load_button.on_click(lambda: on_button_click(stock1_text.value, stock2_text.value, 
                                             date_picker_from.value, date_picker_to.value,
                                             indicator_choice.value))

layout = column(stock1_text, stock2_text, date_picker_from, date_picker_to, indicator_choice, load_button)

curdoc().clear()
curdoc().add_root(layout)



I am very new to this and don't understand why the terminal is saying I wrote 'tow' on line 9, I originally made a typo, but I did fix it to say 'row'. I am unable to find the solution anywhere.
